# Apple Watch workout session without green lights

Tags: apple-watch, hkhealthstore

The green LEDs are eating the battery of the Apple Watch. I would like to run a workout session without checking Heart-Rate, thus no need to turn those leds on - but they still on whenever I do `HKHealthStore()` start `HKWorkoutSession()`.

Is there a way to use these functions without checking heart rate?

Comment: The user can do this, "Save power while you work out" https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204523

Comment: Thanks, however I don't want to ask him to disable this option globally - he needs it when he's doing other workouts. Can I execute a workout session in my app with the green leds lights off?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm still waiting for it.

Comment: Is there any type of workout which can be enabled and result in low battery consumption?